# iPhone / iPad game application dev tools

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, xamarin.ios, unity-game-engine

So I've spent the past week researching on all the different tools you can use to create an iPhone or iPad application game and I still haven't reached a conclusion on which software ( Xcode, unity, mono touch or oolong engine ) to use.

What I am wanting to create are simple yet fun games like ( Fruit Ninja or Cut the rope ).

I've tried researching the software the above games use but no luck.

Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Many thanks!

Comment: A lot of games use Cocos2D, so far as I know, you can't create 3D games with that, but you can make 2D games that can be a lot of fun! (Cocos2D is a library which you import into xcode and code using Xcode) Good Luck!

Answer (score 5):

For us "monotouchers" the best tool for 3D game development on iPhone/iPad doesn't exist yet IMHO.

MonoTouch MonoGame is still too limited, and Cocos2D lacks 3D and is too complex and cumbersome.

But the solution is coming in the future from the Apple "Scene Kit" Framework.

SceneKit is an intuitive wrapper for OpenGL, similar to the Core Animation data visualization API introduced by Apple in OSX Mountain Lion, and consistent with the APIs of Apple's other graphical frameworks.
Scene Kit is designed to import COLLADA 3D objects, and provides intuitive tools for manipulating scenes, lights, cameras, meshes, bounding volumes, geometry, materials and shaders.

For now SceneKit is only available on Mountain Lion, but in the future it will be available on the iOS platform. And I'm sure that the Xamarin guys will be ready to provide us with a MonoTouch version of the library when it will be included in the next iOS SDK.

You can read about the Scene Kit framework here:

[Scene Kit on Mountain Lion - Ars Technica Review](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/07/os-x-10-8/16/#scene-kit)

[Apple WWDC 2012 Session 504 Video: Introducing Scene Kit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?include=504#504)

[Apple WWDC 2012 Session 504 Slides : Introducing Scene Kit](http://adcdownload.apple.com//wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_session_pdfs/session_504__introducing_scene_kit.pdf)

[SceneKit in Mountain Lion review by Jonathan Blocksom, iOS course co-creator](http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/754-scenekit-in-mountain-lion/)

[Scene Kit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/SceneKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012282)

[Scene Kit Editor](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-scene_kit_editor/Articles/Adjusting3DScenes.html)

Comment: "but in the future it will be available on the iOS platform" - That's a bit of an assumption, given that Apple has not even hinted at this. People insisted for years that garbage collection would come over from the Mac to iOS, but it never did and is now deprecated. SceneKit is fantastic, but it may not appear on iOS in its current form, and even if it does it will be more than a year before we see it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Brad.  SceneKit is definitely a slick tool, and right now it seems like it would be a great addition to iOS, but beyond that we just don't know.

Comment: Now that it's out, SceneKit is a good choice, but is there an equivalent for Android?

Answer (score 1):

Well, First of all, you need to determine what is your game gonna be, 2D or 3D, depending on your question, you want a 2D game, that's great, there is a lot of engine around the internet that have a great resources and tutorials, you can try [Cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/), It has a very powerful capabilities and it's community is great.

You can see a list of game engins in this [site](http://www.moddb.com/engines/).

Happy coding.

Comment: Say I wanted to create Cut the rope or something similar - can coscos and Xcode do that for me?

Comment: Absolutely, It's a powerful engine, and don't forget, the success factor for any engine is it's community and resources, Cocos2d has an amazing community and a lot of resources.

Answer (score 1):

I just have two questions.

- What languages do you already know?
- Do you wish to do cross platform to Android later?

With Cocos2D it is iOS specific (I think?) and would require a full re-write to support Android.

I am familiar with XNA and C# so the use of [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/) was my first choice.
I'd build my own game engine within it, but then using that same engine with little changing I should be able to get it to also run on Android, Windows Phone 7, Windows, Linux and OSX.

You can see the platform support matrix [here](http://monogame.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Platform%20support%20matrix&referringTitle=Documentation)

Using something like Unity3D or even UDK is handy as the engine is pre-built and you can do some amazing things with them for 2D games they can be tricky to get them to do what you want.

Comment: I know XHTML,HTML,CSS,CSS3,HTML5,XML,XSLT,.NET and a little bit of C#. Android possibly later but for now IOS. Thanks for the info! Will check it out :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a detailed list of tool which work with Cocos2D: http://abitofcode.com/2012/07/cocos2d-useful-tools/

If you want you can found a tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14302/how-to-make-a-game-like-fruit-ninja-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-part-1) which explain you how to make a Fruit Ninja game using Cocos2D.

Answer (score 1):

[Corona](http://www.coronalabs.com/products/corona-sdk/) is probably the best choice. I haven't made a game in it myself, but I have been developing a 2D game engine for iOS with a Lua interface. [Corona](http://www.coronalabs.com/products/corona-sdk/) is also programmed in Lua, which is a very popular (in the game industry) and easy to learn script language. [Corona](http://www.coronalabs.com/products/corona-sdk/) seems to have a good toolchain and there are a lot of third party software to help you design levels, sprites etc. There are plenty of discussions on the internet about it an Cocoas 2D if you google. The consensus seems to be that [Corona](http://www.coronalabs.com/products/corona-sdk/) is easier to use, but that Cocos2D has the advantages that come from being open source: easy to customize, merge with other code, community etc.